# How to set font size for minitoc in LyX

Tags: lyx, fontsize, minitoc

Hi all I'm writing a book in LyX with the package `minitoc`. If i use `\documentclass [10pt]{book}` the minitoc is set in one page, but if I use `12pt` the minitoc is set in 2 pages.

I want use the 12 pt but resize minitoc like was in 11pt!

Latex code:

```
%% LyX 2.0.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,italian]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle={\ttfamily},
breaklines=true,
frame=TRBL,
frameround=ffff}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{minitoc}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont }{\tiny}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\tableofcontents{}

\begin{singlespace}

\chapter{\noindent Cap1}
\end{singlespace}

\begin{singlespace}
\noindent \null 
\vfill
\begin{singlespace}
\minitoc
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .
\end{singlespace}
\end{singlespace}


\section{Sec1}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\subsection{SubSec2}


\section{Sec2}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\subsection{SubSec2}


\section{Sec3}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\subsection{SubSec2}


\section{Sec4}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\section{Sec5}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\subsection{SubSec2}


\section{Sec6}


\subsection{SubSec1}


\subsection{SubSec2}


\section{Sec7}
\end{document}
```

with 10p the output is:
[toc in 1 page](http://ge.tt/7TceH3T1/v/0?c)

with 12p the output is:
[toc in 2 pages](http://ge.tt/7TceH3T1/v/1?c)

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. I'm not sure exactly how this looks in LyX, but try adding an ERT (Insert --> TeX code) just before the minitoc, and write `{\small` in this, then insert a second ERT just after the minitoc, and write `}` here.

Comment: no it doesn't work :-( \small doesn't resize minitoc.

Comment: OK. Could you create a minimal example, as described in http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample Then edit your post to include either the exported LaTeX (File --> Export --> LaTeX (pdflatex)), or the contents of the `.lyx` file itself. (Open the `.lyx` in a text editor, e.g. Notepad, copy everything, paste it into your question.)

Comment: ok. I have done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to add `tight` as an option to the `minitoc` package, i.e.

```
\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}
```

This will set the minitocs with tighter vertical spacing, which will make it fit on one page.